# Could access DB yesterday, today it refuses to connect (0.0.0.0/0 allowed)

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

So, I've created a postgres database yesterday for my Keycloak instance (oidc).
Opened all ports with `0.0.0.0/0`:
[0.0.0.0/0 opens everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCwKL.png)

Today I log into to proceed with my instalation and refuses to connect:

[Nothing has changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rmkA.png)

It also showers me with logs that it can not connect (who sends them? what can even send them?)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtDTG.png)

Also, if we look at histogram it didn't happen at once when I deployed it yesterday, it happened only somewhere at 9:00PM yesterday.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHHMd.png)

I followed the tutorials given [Connect using a psql client](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip?authuser=4#configure-instance-mysql), and it worked, but now I can't connect to neither of my databases (even freshly created ones).

Appreciate your help...

And, of course, it is possible to connect from cloud shell, so it's just the firewall that does not let me through for some reason, but why?

Also, my keycloak can connect still. Even though it uses public IP.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJUgA.png)

Comment: The error message given by the (unknown) tool from your 2nd image is pretty useless.  What is the error message from your attempt to connect using `psql`?  You say it failed, but didn't give the error message.

Comment: You say that keycloak can connect, but the image you show indicates a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, it actually can connect, from App Engine and containers, but it can't from the outside.

Well, it works, at least.

Whoever is seeing this answer, check, maybe it actually will work from the inside.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).